# AltBeacon not detecting iBeacon after app restart on Android pre-8

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm using AltBeacon with a custom parser for iBeacons. I have a Service which implements `BootstrapNotifier` and sets the custom parser during initialisation:

```
const val IBEACON_LAYOUT = "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"

val parser = BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(IBEACON_LAYOUT)
BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).apply {
    beaconParsers.clear()
    beaconParsers.add(parser)
}

regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, monitoredRegions)
```

I add a region to be monitored like this:

```
fun addRegion(uuid: ByteArray, name: String) {
    val region = Region(name, Identifier.fromBytes(uuid, 0, 16, false), null, null)
    regionBootstrap?.addRegion(region)

    Timber.d("Monitoring region $name")
}
```

I have overrides for `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` and all is working fine if the app is in the foreground or background. If I quit the app by sliding right from the "running apps" screen in Android then the app gets restarted and beacon detection continues - but only for the default AltBeacon type, not iBeacons. It seems like the custom beacon setting is being lost, possibly because the setting is not synced to the AltBeacon service. I've tried adding the iBeacon parser when calling `addRegion` but no success. The only thing which works for me is to modify a local copy of AltBeacon so that it defaults to iBeacon.

Anyone have success using a custom parser after app restart?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your service.never gets started after killing the app, and as a result, when the library wakes up to scan using the JobScheduler, the BeaconParser never gets set.

The simple solution is to set your BeaconParser in a custom Application class's onCreate method.  This always gets executed when the app starts up, even if the start up is simply to do a scan based on a JobScheduler.